# How to combine DOM javascript and Blade PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Currently i'm using laravel right now, but i tried to combbine the HTML with DOM. Here is the code that' i tried to use.

```
//DOM
let collapseManual = 
`
<div class="card-body">
   <div class="card mt-3 mb-3 shadow">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        @include('PrivilegeModul.NewModul.tableheader')
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
`;
```

And here is the result

[image]

How to make it's work?

Comment: Blade templates (and regular PHP code) are processed on the server, the result is HTML (+ inline JS), which is sent to the browser. Here, DOM manipulation takes over, but all server data has to be either already inserted or loaded via ajax now. Javascript files aren't processed by Laravel, so stuff like `@include` won't work in them.

Comment: To make it work you will have to process the `@include` in a `.blade.php` file. You can push data from the server to javascript by using a `<script>` tag (even if is not the best solution)

Comment: Thank your for explanations